# How to change the background color of pop up header?

Tags: html, css, popup

I am getting issue in background color on popup  header.I  am trying to change the background color of pop up header using below code but its not working. The header background color for the popup not taking the below css. Please help me.

**HTML**

```
    <a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>
        <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">

                        <div class="pop-header">
                            <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
                        </div>
    </div>
```

**css**

```
    .pop-header
    {
         width: 100%;
         background-color: #000;
         height: 50px;
         padding: 20px;
    }


    .modalDialog {
        position: fixed;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        z-index: 99999;
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        pointer-events: none;
    }


    .modalDialog:target {
        opacity:1;
        pointer-events: auto;
    }

    .modalDialog > div {
        width: 600px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 2% auto;
        padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: #fff;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .close
    {
        float: right;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Check my updated answer if you want to change only header part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change color `background` in `.modalDialog > div` css.

```
.modalDialog > div {
        width: 600px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 2% auto;
        padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: red; //Here
        height: 100%;
    }
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awgt02m9/3/)**

**Edit:**

If you want to change color of only header part then you should put one div parent to `.pop-header`

```
<div>
  <div class="pop-header">
  <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
</div>
```

And css:

```
.pop-header
    {
       width: 100%;
       background-color: red;
       height: 50px;
    }
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awgt02m9/4/)**

Check as per your image

**[New Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awgt02m9/5/)**

Comment: Please check the above image .You will get idea.

Comment: @Hybreeder check my new fiddle.

Comment: @Hybreeder glad to help. Don't forget to mark as a answer.

Comment: Sure,I need little more help Mr.ketan

Comment: Check this link without header background(This is body part) https://jsfiddle.net/Narendra2015/zckezwkh/                                         Check this link with header background(header part)
   https://jsfiddle.net/Narendra2015/aq197q73/

Comment: In the below  HTML code, Comment part is header code if i removed the comment its talking only header part  annd if i removed the header code than its talking body part.I need with header and body part both. Please help me.

Comment: @Hybreeder Put `container` div inside new div that is `modalDialog > div` Don't put it outside. check https://jsfiddle.net/zckezwkh/1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101261/discussion-between-hybreeder-and-ketan).

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one:

```
 .pop-header
    {
         width: 100%;
         background-color: #000!important;
         height: 50px;
         padding: 20px;

    }


    .modalDialog {
        position: fixed;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        z-index: 99999;
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        pointer-events: none;
    }


    .modalDialog:target {
        opacity:1;
        pointer-events: auto;
    }

    .modalDialog > div {
        width: 600px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 2% auto;
        padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: #fff;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .close
    {
        float: right;
        color:white;
    }
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/awgt02m9/2/)

**Or**

```
.pop-header
    {
         width: 100%;
         background-color: #000!important;
         height: 50px;
         padding: 20px;

    }

.pop-header p
{
  color:white;
  background-color:blue;
  float:left;
  margin:0px;

  width:100%;
  top:0px;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:8px;
}

    .modalDialog {
        position: fixed;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        z-index: 99999;
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
        pointer-events: none;
    }


    .modalDialog:target {
        opacity:1;
        pointer-events: auto;
    }

    .modalDialog > div {
        width: 600px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 2% auto;
        padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: #fff;
        height: 100%;

    }

    .close
    {
        float: right;
        color:white;
        position:absolute;
        top:13px;
         right:10px;
    }
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/awgt02m9/7/)

Comment: I need only header part.

Answer (score 0):

replace your .pop-header class with below :

```
.pop-header
    {
         width: 100%;
         background-color: #000!important;
         height: 50px!important;
         padding: 20px;
    }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.Sanjeev,I need only header background color its taking full my popup background  .

Comment: I have edited the class above see if this one helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The popup header rule is ignored, using !important will make sure nothing can override it you could just put this rule at the end of the style sheet.

```
.pop-header
    {
         width: 100%;
         background-color: #000 !important;
         height: 50px;
         padding: 20px;
    }
```